# Visit counter stored to a file using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-io

Hi I'm wondering how to do just a simple visit counter that stores the information into a file the format could be something like: Date | # Visits, this is just a POC that I'm trying to do here nothing complicated I just want to get use to this framework.

I was trying to use the [file helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html) and the [string helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/string_helper.html) to read the file and then subtract the date or split the content and use a loop to iterate the and update the current date

this is the code so far ...

namespace libraries;

```
class VisitCounter {

    function __construct() {
        $this->load->library('file');
        $this->load->helper('string');
    }

    function trackVisit(){
        $file= read_file('./visits.txt');

        if ( ! write_file('./visits.txt', $file)){
            echo 'Unable to write the file';
        }
    }
}
```

Any Ideas, I need to know how to split the string or if someone has a better approach.

Comment: Are you going to read the file, then append a line to it, then write all the lines to disk?

Comment: yes I want to save that into a file the format could be the following: *-*-*   Visits   *-*-*

05/19/12 - 74
05/20/12 - 68

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a model for doing that:

```
class Count_model extends CI_Model{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function increment(){
        $this->db->set('total', 'total+1', FALSE);
        $this->db->update('count');
    }

    function get_total(){
        $query = $this->db->get('count');
        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            $row = $query->row();
            return str_pad($row->total, 6 , "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

}
```

Heres the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `count` (
  `total` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`total`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: that's nice. but when this file should we run ??

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution would be using a database.

Anyway, if you want to write to a text file, you can use [serialize](http://be1.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to convert an array to a string which can be saved into a file, and [unserialize](http://be1.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to convert the string back into an array.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked for me:

```
function increment($id){
    $this->db->set('page_opens', 'page_opens+1', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('page');
}
```